# Android: AppWidget design and layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-appwidget

I would like to have an AppWidget that designed like [this one](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kanokgems.smswidget&feature=search_result).

Image:

[image]

I have searched the web for assitance, but couldn't find any.

Particularly:
I want an appwidget wich consist of an imageButton, and a textView that will be **placed in front of it** (like in the picture above).

The closest solution I have found so far is by relativeLayout but it still doesn't place the textView **on the imageButton**.

Will be happy to get any help for designing AppWidgets like that one.

Thanks Advanced, Gal.

Comment: Check my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522812/how-to-create-an-inbox-style-with-unread-count-widget-for-android/6522983#6522983).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522983/988434) to solve it, (Linked by alextsc in the comments).

A relative layout is indeed used, I managed to achieve the desired effect by using this configurations:

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="72dp">
        <ImageButton android:background="@null" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/phone_draw" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/call" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></ImageButton>
        <TextView android:textColor="@color/green" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/missedCalls" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:background="@drawable/missed_call_bg" android:text="3" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:typeface="sans" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Where the image button is the big icon, and the TextView is the little counter icon.

Hope it will help you too! =]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout. The items in these layouts are added in the order read in XML, so to make your TextView sit infront of your ImageView, just write ImageView, then TextView. 
Then nest each one of these widget views into a GridLayout, to get that homeview layout.

Try looking at the API Examples under layout. Good examples in there.